# 1 TB Dell USB hard disk not getting recognized

Tags: 11.10, usb, usb-drive

Dell USB hard disk not recognized in Ubuntu 11.10

When I insert the USB disk I do not see it in Nautilus (left hand pane) 
lsusb surprisingly fails to report any pciid:vendor id related to the removable usb inserted
I checked when the disk was not attached

> sudo lsusb > without_disk

and when disk was attached

> sudo lsusb >with_disk

and

> diff without_disk with_disk

there was no difference

and also checked dmesg

the only thing after inserting USB in the USB slot dmesg shows is

```
[   69.540224] usb 2-1: new high speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[   69.674505] scsi7 : uas
[   69.675815] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Dell     USB Portable HDD 040D PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
```

I do not see any pci id: vendor id combination with lsusb for this 1 TB hard disk.
The hard disk is working correctly on a Windows 7 system so problem here is with Ubuntu 11.10 only. What could be the issue? It is a new USB hard disk [this one](http://www.flipkart.com/dell-1tb-usb-3-0-portable-hard-drive/p/itmdffjygqrxghng)

Comment: Did you try it with a newer version of Ubuntu, maybe using it in Live mode? If it does work, the issue can be that the disk is too much new for Oneiric.

Comment: thanks yes I upgraded it now and it has worked.....

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11334979&postcount=17

I tried a `rmmod uas` and it worked :)